# Fonts are not recognized at Android Studio

Tags: java, fonts, android-studio

My Android Studio doesn't recognize fonts in .ttf or .otf format.
I searched for them at File--> Settings -->File Types , but there i can't find a category which recognizes this formats...
Am I alone with this problem?

Because of my new Membership I can't upload any pics, so here a link to a picture of my problem

[image: http://fs2.directupload.net/images/141222/r23r74to.jpg]

Comment: http://fs2.directupload.net/images/141222/r23r74to.jpg     Can you now watch in pls. thx

Answer (score 0):

It is common for android studio (even in latest version) . I also have "?" mark in project explorer, however it is not problem in programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your custom fonts directly in java.
First get a reference to the `TextView` displaying the text that you want to apply your custom font to. Then call the `TypeFace` class’s `createFromAsset()` method to create a new type face using your custom font. You pass an instance of the app's `AssetManager` as the first parameter by calling `getAssets()`. This enables you to access the custom font asset file which you pass as the second parameter.

Finally, call `setTypeFace()` to apply your custom font to the text.

```
TextView  textViewCustom= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textCustomViewFont);
Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/xyz.ttf");
   textViewCustom.setTypeface(custom_font);
```

Android custom fonts tutorial TypeFace java

Create a new `TypeFace` using your custom font, `xyz.ttf` which is saved in the `assets/fonts` folder. You can do it in XML also.